# Android:RTSP Stream Stops playing after 1 minute

Tags: android, rtsp

public class RTSPViewer extends Activity implements
        MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener, SurfaceHolder.Callback {
    final static String USERNAME = "";
    final static String PASSWORD = "";
    private String RTSP_URL;
    //
    private MediaPlayer _mediaPlayer;
    private SurfaceHolder _surfaceHolder;
    //
    private SharedPreferences preference;
    private String PREFS_NAME = "LoginPrefs";

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    // requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    Window window = getWindow();
    window.setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    window.setBackgroundDrawableResource(android.R.color.white);
    setContentView(R.layout.rtspviewer);
    preference = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    surfaceHandling();

}

public void surfaceHandling() {

    RTSP_URL = /* "rtsp://192.168.1.6:8554/CAM1"; */getIntent()
            .getExtras().getString("CAMERA_IP").toString();
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "" + RTSP_URL,
            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    Log.d("---CAMVIEW---", "" + RTSP_URL);
    SurfaceView surfaceView = (SurfaceView) findViewById(R.id.surfaceView1);
    _surfaceHolder = surfaceView.getHolder();
    _surfaceHolder.addCallback(this);
    _surfaceHolder.setFixedSize(320, 240);
}

@Override
public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder sh, int f, int width, int height) {
    Log.v("2", "surfaceChanged");
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
}

@Override
public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder sh) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Log.v("1", "surfaceCreated");
    _mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
    _mediaPlayer.setDisplay(_surfaceHolder);

    Context context = getApplicationContext();
    // Map<String, String> headers = getRtspHeaders();
    Uri source = Uri.parse(RTSP_URL);
    Log.i("headers----->", "Source String:" + source);

    try {
        // Specify the IP camera's URL and auth headers.
        _mediaPlayer.setDataSource(context, source, null/* headers */);

        // Begin the process of setting up a video stream.
        _mediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(this);
        _mediaPlayer.prepareAsync();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO: handle exception
    }
}

@Override
public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder arg0) {
    Log.v("nnnnn", "surfaceDestroyed");
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    _mediaPlayer.release();
}

@Override
public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
    Log.v("0", "onPrepared");
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    // mp.reset();
    // mp.start();
    // _mediaPlayer.reset();
    _mediaPlayer.start();
}
```

}

Comment: No Log cat error just stop working suddenly!

Comment: I run into this same problem with VideoView. Mine will resume play if I wait about 15-20 seconds. this occurs once every minute. Possibly an issue with reaching the end of a one minute buffer? Yet to try it with SurfaceView.